# How to append custom buttons when fullscreen of another div of visjs graph is triggered?

Tags: vis.js-network, vis.js

Currently I can toggle a fullscreen of visjs network graph. However, I want to add some custom buttons. Currently I haven't find a way to embed the button inside the visjs graph. So when I toggle the fullscreen of visjs network graph, the buttons are gone. May I know that is there a way I can append the buttons to a certain position when fullscreen is triggered? Thank you so much
[layout of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfawl.jpg)

Comment: Can't you just use some absolut positioning to but the buttons on top of the network? And then hide these buttons when you click the ful screen? What you got so far?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Currently my button is: <%= button_to "Reset",resetsocialnetwork_path(id:params[:id]),method: :get,remote:true, class: "btn btn-info", id: "resetbtn"%>

Comment: and my fullscreen function is:  var networkfullscreen = document.getElementById("visnetwork");
    
  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
      if (networkfullscreen.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        networkfullscreen.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        networkfullscreen.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      }
    } else {
      if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }
  }

Comment: I still haven't find a way to solve this. when I toogle fullscreen of the visnetwork div, the button is  outside the div, so it won't be shown in  fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I got what you need right you want to make the network go fullscreen and keep the button on the left and add custom buttons when fullscreen.

To do it, one solution I think it might work is to wrap your network and your buttons in a single `div`. Then, instead of making only the network `div` fullscreen, you would make the whole container go fullscreen. To toggle which buttons are visible, you can listen for the [Full Screen Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) and play around with the `display` property in each button.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7Lg99n9/

Here, I have a button to make it go full screen and then I have a button that is only showed when in full screen mode.

Is that enough for you?

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried this method the buttons appear now. But when in fullscreen mode the graph with the button do not fulfill the whole screen. I make the container 100% height and width and the #mynetwork:-webkit-full-screen 100% width and height, but still the size only depends on its size on normal mode. May I know how to adjust this? Thank you so much! Here's how it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/yingli40604345/e7Lg99n9/16/

Comment: Nice! So, it was not full width and height because the CSS on top of your `#mynetwork:-webkit-full-screen` was having fixed `height` and `width` values. Setting that to a `100%` does the trick. I also did some absolute positioning so the button would appear on top of the network and dont move it down: http://jsfiddle.net/g4msjx94/

Comment: Thank you soooo much for your help! Looks so nice! But I got some other buttons and elements in this page, may I know that should I make everyone's position absolute or is there a way to only modify the network and fullscreen button on fullscreen mode? Now when I make network's position absolute, button F and G will jump to the top of the page on normal mode and something like that.  Oh I just add page layout picture in the question description since I can't upload pic in comment

Comment: In that case, maybe its better to only absolute position the `fullscreen-only-button`. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/deat56gw/
One other alternative, you can dynamically change the `position` property of your network to `static` or `relative` just like we do with `display` for the button that is only showing when it is full screen

Comment: Thank you so much!! But if I made the height of the network 100% , it can not have the same height with the left card. Currently my layout is like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/yingli40604345/e7Lg99n9/36/     If I change the height from 400px to 100% it will be very short in normal mode. May I know that is there any method to make it have the same height with the left card in original mode? I'm so sorry for so many questions...Thank you so much!

Comment: You can dynamically set the `height` property to change from `400px` to `100%` when you toggle the fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/p5hdn1kt/

Comment: OMG! Thank you soooo much!!! It works! You're a genius :D This is a really really good method which I think I can use it to solve many many issues!! I really should learn more about javascript lol!

Comment: Hahahaha not even close to a genius! Javascript is a really great and useful language indeed. You will get used to it :)
If this solves your issue, would you mind checking my answer above as the correct one? Thanks! :D